# Custom Domain on Change Password screen

Tags: force.com-sites, community, mydomain

I have a salesforce community with a custom domain (mysite.com).

When a user uses the reset password functionality, they get an email which includes a reset password link pointed to the force.com domain e.g. `force.com/login?c=<big token>`.

Clicking that link redirects a user to the change password screen, also on the force.com domain: `force.com/_ui/system/security/ChangePassword`.

I was hoping I could just change the forgot password email template so the link points to my domain instead: `mysite.com/login?c=<big token>`...but it seems this does not work.

I'm not sure on the best way to proceed here.  Is this maybe a job for a URL rewriter?  Do I build a custom change password page and send the users there instead?  Am I not configuring my community correctly?

**Edits**: Trying to go down the path of building out a visualforce page which handles the password change.

I am confused how it is possible to use `Site.forgotPassword()` in conjunction with `Site.changePassword()`.  When you call forgotPassword, in the context of a community, the email that goes out does not contain the temporary password.  Instead it contains the type of link shown above, `force.com/login?c=<confirmation token>`.  However, the `changePassword` call requires the temporary password.

How can I get a temporary password in my community forgot password email?  If I cant do that can I read in the confirmation token on my custom page somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, custom domains are not possible with SSL/HTTPS, which is required for the specific use case you're talking about here.